# how to get specific data inside class?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Let's say I have a data class like below.

```
export class TestData extends JsonObject {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    sold: {
       number: number;
       price: number;
       total: string;
    }
}
```

And I can receive from my component like so:

```
 myData:TestData  = new TestData();
    this.myData.name = "Test"
```

How can i set a data for price inside sold?

Comment: this.myData.sold.price = 42 ?

Comment: i tried that but i get this error: Cannot set property 'price ' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Like this :

This assumes that sold is already defined.

```
this.myData.sold.price = your_price;
```

If not then

```
this.myData.sold = {};
this.myData.sold.price = your_price;
```

Comment: This assumes that `sold` is already defined. It won't be in the snippet posted in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would declare a setter method to mutate your sold object like this:

```
export class TestData extends JsonObject {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    sold: {
       number: number;
       price: number;
       total: string;
    }
    setSold: (number, price, total) => {
        object.assign({}, this.sold, {number, price, total})
    }
}
```

You can call the method like this:

```
TestData.setSold(number, number, "string");
```

Don't forget to instanciate your class using the `new` keyword before trying to change it.

```
const testData = new TestData();
testData.setSold(1, 5, "total");
```

**Further information**

- [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)